# Laravel lock table to prevent duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here's the issue.

I have a code which creates invoices and for every new invoice I take the last invoice in the DB and increase the number by 1.

The problem is sometimes when multiple administrators are using the system and **at the same time they create a new invoice**, the number, which should be unique gets duplicated.
This is happening because the first invoice has not yet been saved in the DB and **the generateInvoiceNumber function gets called again**.

Here is the code:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

$number = $this->generateInvoiceNumber($company);

$invoice = new Invoice;
$invoice->basket()->associate($basket);
$invoice->company()->associate($company);
$invoice->number = $number;

// Other stuff here...

DB::commit();
```

Here's the generate invoice number function (I am using lockForUpdate which I thought would solve the issue, but sadly it did not):

```
private function generateInvoiceNumber(Company $company)
{
    $invoices = Invoice::lockForUpdate()->where('company_id', $company->id)->orderByDesc('number')->get();

    if ($invoices->count() > 0) {
        return ++$invoices->first()->number;
    }

    return $company->starting_number ?? 1;
}
```

How can I assure that I won't have such duplicates ?
I guess it is with locking, but it seems I don't know enough about DB locks to solve it.

Comment: since last invoice ID is stored in DB you dont need to fetch it you can use insert + select something like this INSERT into table (invoice_id) SELECT max(invoice_id) + 1  FROM table

Comment: why not setting that column as `AUTO_INCREMENT`ed ?

Comment: @ths Laravel allows only one `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam yes you are right, even `MySQL` would require to have a composite `PK` then. Maybe, using the `id` on that table, assuming you, @Angel, set one (which you should do). The `id` itself becomes your invoice number. That's a potential solution, I won't say it will work as that depends on your requirements and setup.

Comment: @bobi It is not a problem with the ID. I am using a custom field for the number because it should be seperated.

Comment: @AngelMiladinov b4 open the create page add a dummy record, and change your POST to PUT. I ran same issue and solved by using this. works like update each tome with ID

Comment: @AbdullaNilam This would create another problem - on the opening of the create page the same issue may happen - 2 users open the page at almost the same time. Another thing is - the other user may not press the update button and therefore there will be a hole in the numbers - 123, 125. I don't want this.

Comment: @AngelMiladinov A and B users open the page, and B users query hit the DB, create id for him ex 95 if B user gets the error to create new id for him `96`.

Comment: @AngelMiladinov or create id with current timestamp with milliseconds.